# Getting search results from wikidata website, but not API

Tags: wikipedia-api, wikidata, wikidata-api

I'm trying out the wikidata API but have some trouble with the search query "Jas 39 C Gripen". It returns results on the wikidata website, but not if I use the API.

On The wikidata website I get two search results for the query

https://www.wikidata.org/w/index.php?search=Jas+39+C+Gripen&title=Special:Search&fulltext=1

The same query using the API, does not return a result

https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbsearchentities&format=json&language=en&type=item&continue=0&search=Jas%2039%20C%20Gripen

Am I missing some parameters or using the wrong parameters? For many other queries I get results from the API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the native Wikidata search applies some "fuzzy logic" when interpreting the user's entries. In your case, it shows two results, although the character `C` is missing in the first one.

Coming back to the API **and the action you have chosen**, you could use `Jas 39 Gripen` as search term (which will show one result) as well as `Jas 39C Gripen` (which will also show one result). But it seems that you can't use `Jas 39 C Gripen` (note the space character between `9` and `C`).

In other words,

```
https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbsearchentities&format=json&language=en&type=item&continue=0&search=Jas%2039%20Gripen
https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbsearchentities&format=json&language=en&type=item&continue=0&search=Jas%2039C%20Gripen
```

both work, but

```
https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbsearchentities&format=json&language=en&type=item&continue=0&search=Jas%2039%20C%20Gripen
```

does not.

I have investigated this issue further and finally **found the solution**. Try this:

```
https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&format=json&srsearch=Jas+39+C+Gripen
```

The action `query` allows some "fuzziness" in the search term. Please refer to the API documentation for further details. In short, this action performs a full text search (which you obviously want) and allows for a `nearmatch` search type.

Answer (score 2):

The reason seems to be that the English label is JAS 39C Gripen. By removing one space from your query, you will get the result you are looking for:

https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbsearchentities&format=json&language=en&type=item&continue=0&search=Jas%2039C%20Gripen

Comment: Correct, but the OP still does get only *one* entry returned that way. If I understood the question correctly, the OP wants to get *the same result from the API as if using the search box*, which means two entries in this case.